# LWC - How would I refresh the data of a lightning-datatable after a new record is created?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am using the wire service along with an apex controller to initially fetch the data.

Like this: `@wire (fetchAccounts)parameters`.

I would like to be able to view the newly created account on the datatable as:

```html
    <lightning-datatable 
       key-field="id"
       data={parameters.data}
       onrowaction={handleRowAction}
       row-number-offset={rowOffset}
       hide-checkbox-column="true"
       columns={columns}>
    </lightning-datatable>
```

What is the right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve this, the documentation can be found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex#data_apex__refresh_cache.

So that would look like this:

```js
// add this import statement
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
```

```js
    @track parameters;
    @track error;

    /** Wired Apex result so it can be refreshed programmatically */
    _wiredResult;

    @wire(fetchAccounts)
    wiredCallback(result) {
        this._wiredResult = result;
        if (result.data) {
            this.parameters = result.data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
            this.parameters = undefined;
        }
    }

    // in order to refresh your data, execute this function:
    refreshData() {
        return refreshApex(this._wiredResult);
    }
```

And change your HTML to:

```html
<lightning-datatable 
   key-field="id"
   data={parameters}
   onrowaction={handleRowAction}
   row-number-offset={rowOffset}
   hide-checkbox-column="true"
   columns={columns}>
</lightning-datatable>
```

If you want to read a nice sample for this, you can find that here: https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsDeleteRecord/ldsDeleteRecord.js

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot, your solution worked haha. I had tried this earlier but without success. The issue was the parameters.data. Thanks again for your help, appreciate it.

Comment: @Draccel Good to hear, can you please mark my response as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You needs to call `refreshApex` after the call to server (inside `.then()` callback)
Here is working example to how to achieve refresh on html data after changing something on database:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import findSomething from '@salesforce/apex/ApexController.findMethod';
import changeSomething from '@salesforce/apex/ApexController.changeMethod';
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';

findSomething
changeSomething
@track paramForChangeOne
@track paramForChangeTwo

@wire(findSomething, { paramOne: '$paramOne', paramTwo: '$paramTwo' }) findSomething;

callFromHtml(){
    changeSomething({paramForChangeOne: this.paramForChangeOne, paramForChangeTwo: this.paramForChangeTwo})
    .then(result => {
        if(result){
            this.showNotification('success', 'Success Message', '');
        }
        // refreshing table data using refresh apex(HERE NEEDS TO BE SET)
        refreshApex(this.findSomething);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```